# xmmintrin.h vs gcc vector extensions

Tags: gcc, sse, simd

Which method should I prefer to write SIMD instructions?

*mm** methods form *mmintrin.h seem to be more portable across compilers.

But gcc [vector extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) seems to produce mush simpler code, and to support more architectures.

So which method is the best?

Comment: You can use both. That's what I do.  The vector extensions cover most vertical operations which is what you should use most of the time. When you need other operations you can cast. For example if you have a 16 byte vector `x` you can do `_mm_movemask_epi8((__m128i)x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the gcc vector extensions you will only be able to use a limited subset of SSE functionality, since there are many SSE intrinsics which do not fit in with a generic vector model such as gcc's. If you only want to do fairly basic stuff, e.g. floating point arithmetic on vectors, then you might get away with it, but if you are interested in exploiting SIMD for maximum performance benefit then you'll need to go with the native intrinsics.

Answer (score 2):

The intrinsics available from the *mmintrin.h files are available only on SSE machines, but they are available across different compilers. The GCC vector extensions are more limited but implemented on a wider range of platforms, and obviously GCC specific.

As with everything, there is no 'best' answer; you'll have to choose one that fits your needs.